# Библиотека owlcarousel2 прокрутка колесика

Tags: javascript, slider, owl-carousel

Есть ли параметры, которые отвечают за прокрутку колесика мыши? Иначе он крутиться только в одну сторону справа налево.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это из документации

```js
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Хм, у меня проблема с deltaY. Он в консоль выводит undefined видимо из-за этого скрипт не просчитывает координаты. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Все решил. Это из-за jquery. Вот решение let delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY; И уже в условий вставить данную переменную